# Cannot access data in nested object within Nunjucks template

Tags: javascript, html, templating, nunjucks

Using this template code I can output the `employer` value in `data` object below fine.

```
{% field.value %}
```

But I am not able to get any of the `sections` or the nested `obligatory` 
data to display.

```
var data = {

  "employer": "Employer x",
.....

  "sections": {

    "obligatory": {
      "obligatory-13": {
        "value": "N/A"
      },
      "obligatory-12": {
        "remarks": "Absence",
        "value": "N-C"
      }
    }
}
```

When I use the `{% field.value %}` in the sections template it displays `[object Object]` in the view. But I can't get access to anything inside the object and I can't see inside it either to find out what is going wrong.

I've tried `{{field.value.obligatory}}` because `field.value` should be a handle for the sections object but that doesn't show anything at all.

Just to clear up any confusion the `{{field.value}}` should return the entire `sections` object. It is not a reference to the `value` keys inside the `obligatory` objects.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I tried using [nunjuck's string filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#string) to see the object but it still displays `[object Object]`.

```
{{ field.value | string }}
```

**EDIT**

This is a clearer version of the problem what the final data looks like. Sorry for any confusion with the data structure/naming above.

```
"field": [{

    "value": {
                "obligatory-13": {
                  "value": "N/A"
                },
                "obligatory-12": {
                  "remarks": "Notes",
                  "value": "N-C"
                }
    }
}]
```

And what I am trying to do is:

```
{% for point in field.value %}
  {{ point }}
```

No matter what I try I can't seem to get the `obligatory` objects to display in the template.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Print single item value
{{sections.obligatory['obligatory-12'].value}} // => N-C

// Iterate over sections.obligatory
{% for id, obligatory in sections.obligatory %}
{{id}} : {{obligatory.value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Update

```
{% for id, obligatory in field[0].value %}
{{id}} : {{obligatory.value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Sadly it didn't work. I still can't get access to the nested objects.

Comment: I tried the update but it still doesn't display anything in the view. However, if I do this `{% for id, obligatory in field.value %}` leaving out the zero index it is definitely iterating over the `obligatory` objects because I see same number of `:` in the view. But the actual data values still are showing up.

Comment: Ok, I got it working with `{% for id, obligatory in field.value %}`. I had made a change in my data structure that was stopping the values from showing. But changing the `field[0]` to `field.value` and printing out the data with `{{id}} : {{obligatory.value}}` works.